# Is there a way to get scrollstate from Lazyrow

Tags: list, android-jetpack-compose

I have made a LazyRow that i now want to be able to get the scrollposition from. What i understand Scrollablerow has been deprecated. (correct me if im wrong) The thing is that i cant make a scrollablerow so i thought lets make a lazy one then. but i have no clue how to get scrollposition from the lazyrow. i know how to get index but not position if that eaven exists. here is what i have tried.

```
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
LazyRow(scrollState = scrollstate){

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Lazy`Scrollers, there are separate `Lazy`States.

I think there's just one, in fact, i.e. `rememberLazyListState()`

Pass that as the scroll state to the row and then you can access all kinds of info. For example, you could get the index of the first visible item, as well as its offset. There are direct properties for this stuff in the object returned by the above initialisation. You can also perform some more complex operations using the `lazyListState.layoutInfo` property that you get.

Also, `ScrollableRow` may be deprecated as a `@Composable`, but it is just refactored, a bit. Now, you can use the `horozontalScroll()` and `verticalScroll()` Modifiers, both of which accept a `scrollState` parameter, which expects the same object as the one you've created in the question.

Usually, you'd use `Lazy`Scrollers since they're not tough to implement and also are super-performant, but the general idea is that they are used with large datasets whereas non-lazy scrollers are okay for small sized lists and stuff. This is because the lazy ones cache only a small fraction of the entire list, making your UI peformant, which is not something regular scrollers do, and not a problem for small datasets.

They're like equivalents of `RecyclerView` from the `View` System

Comment: Solving your problem was... Super-easy, barely an inconvenience

Comment: This was very well explained my question was just quz i could not seem to find like an actuall position in the lazyRow Liststate just an index though i could be wrong but i mean with a list that needs no downloading of data it feels like a row with vertical scroll should be enough no?

Comment: Depends. If you row has a lot of elements, maybe 50-100, it should be considered to use Lazy stuff. Then again, if all of those are just simple `Text`s, then you could even have a thousand in a regular scroller. The point is, it depends on the complexity of each item. The simplest way to know is just build the thing in a regular scroller, then check if it lags. It it does, switch to lazy scrolling, or else stick to the regular one.

Comment: Well it will be a bunch of text that is clickable but that's it should i see that as a good place to use just a row?

Comment: Yeah yeah yeah!!

Comment: Also, if it is highly decorative text, like complex UI designs for each Composable, keep in mind that every single Composable would be cached by the regular scroller. If it does not work, i.e., it lags, you could always switch to `Lazy` scrollers nothing to worry about here. Wow wow wow,... wow